# VBA code in Word to check if the current macro is the most recent version

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm creating a macro in Word 2013 to share with my org. However, I want to notify them when the macro is updated. Basically, I'd like them to run the macro, and if it finds a newer version on a network, then creates a message telling them to install the latest version.

I think the simplest solution would be to use FileDateTime("\Server\test\book1.xlsm") to check a file saved to a network, and then if newer than the current macro file, it provides a message: MsgBox "A new version of this macro exists on the network share. Please install the new version."

I know how to find if a file exists, just not how to check if it's more recent:

```
Sub FileExists()

    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim TestStr As String

    FilePath = "D:\FolderName\Sample.xlsx"

    TestStr = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TestStr = "" Then
        MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open "D:\FolderName\Sample.xlsx"
    End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone help piece this together?

Comment: Is the newer version named differently? Because your filename and filepath is static.

Comment: Yes, the newer version will have the same name. Actually, I just need to validate, so I can create an Excel file that has the version number listed within. In the macro, I can input the version number. If the versions don't match, then the macro stops, and I tell the users to install the newer version.

Answer (score 2):

You would do far better to ensure the macro is stored in the document's template, which you'd also store in a network folder where the document can access it, then simply update the template as & when required. That way:

- the document(s) can remain in the docx format;
- users need not be instructed to download macro updates (which I wouldn't count on them doing anyway);
- you can always be sure the version of the macro they're running is the latest one.

Comment: This assumes, though, that they're always connected to the network. A variant approach: store the template on the network and copy it to the appropriate place on their computer in a startup script. The amount of data to be copied will usually be negligible. And this also sidesteps the need to have the user do the job; a real potential point of failure.

Comment: «This assumes, though, that they're always connected to the network». A reasonable assumption, IMHO, and even possible these days for most workers in the field. «A variant approach: store the template on the network and copy it to the appropriate place on their computer in a startup script» Which is just as prone to network issues on startup...

Comment: We plan to store on a network since it's internal only and needs to be protected by our access controls for the site. Our instructions will be to save the macro to the Startup folder so all Word docs can use it. Yes, the newer version will have the same name. I just need to validate, so I can create an Excel file that has the version number listed within. In the macro, I can input the version number. If the versions don't match, then the macro stops, and I tell the users to install the newer version.

Comment: You obviously don't understand the point of my answer, which is that by storing the macro in the document's template in the way described there is no need for all your circumlocution.

Answer (score 1):

The macro should be stored in either the document template in which it is used or in a global template. Both can be stored on network drives. My preference is for them to be used from the local computer and a network login script set to update the local copy if changed using the old XCOPY command.

- My writing on [Global Templates](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Global)
- My writing on [Workgroup Templates](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm#Workgroup)

Workgroup templates are document templates managed for an enterprise or department. Global templates share resources (like macros) with all documents but are not used, themselves to create new documents.